# SMIL Animate SVG "to" value

Tags: html, svg, jquery-animate, svg-animate, smil

I'm trying to animate this SVG rect to end on width 100 but for some reason it keeps resetting to the original value. Help!

http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/RNmNQE

```
<svg>
  <rect height="100" width="10">
    <animate attributeName="width" values="10;100" dur="3s" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the attribute fill="freeze"

```html
<svg>
  <rect height="100" width="10">
    <animate fill="freeze" attributeName="width" from="10" to="100" dur="3s" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```